# Objective-C: Execute block or function in specific NSThread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

`NSObject` has a method `-performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` that allows executing any method on the calling object in a specific `NSThread`.

Is there a similar and convenient way to execute a C-style function or block in a specific `NSThread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSThread` API is largely selector-based. In iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, there is block-based API for the [initializing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsthread/2088561-initwithblock?language=objc) or [detaching](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsthread/2088563-detachnewthreadwithblock?language=objc) of the thread, but not for performing some task on an existing `NSThread`. If you want to use block-based API, you'd generally use dispatch or operation queues, which gets you out of the weeds of managing `NSThread` instances yourself.

But if you google "NSThread block extension", you'll see there are simple third-party APIs to provide block methods for `NSThread`. E.g., [GTMNSThread+Blocks.h](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/blob/master/Foundation/GTMNSThread%2BBlocks.h) or [NSThread-MCSMAdditions](https://github.com/ObjColumnist/NSThread-MCSMAdditions).

Comment: Had a feeling an extension would be the way to go, thanks